# Replacing document.write of external script

Tags: javascript, forms, document.write

Is there any way to replace `document.write` of an external script that I can't edit?

```
<div class="mydiv">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.formstack.com/forms/js.php?3349003-8L4WS0Z6Xi"></script>
</div>
```

I tried the below code to replace it but it just messed up all the things

````
document.write=function(s){
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    var lastScript = scripts[scripts.length-1];
    lastScript.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", s);
}```
````

Comment: what exactly were you trying to achieve with that last snippet?

Comment: i want to use the script but without document.write because of performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to overwrite it, maybe to improve performance with append?

```
document.write = function(s) {
    document.body.append(s)
}
```